# No way to get CloudFront working with my dynamic website

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a hard time to get CloudFront running in front of our dynamic PHP website running on an EC2 instance (PHP with Nginx Webserver - but that should not matter).

The site is running on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (just an example obviously ;-). The webserver listens on example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and public.example.com on ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). It is configured to forward example.com and public.example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and HTTP to HTTPS. HTTPS uses a Let's Encrypt certificate issued for public.example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Using the following settings in CloudFront:

- Distribution

  - **Price class:** Use only North America and Europe
  - **AWS WAF web ACL:** None
  - **Alternate domain name (CNAME):** [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
  - **Custom SSL certificate:** a AWS Certificate Manager issued RSA 2048 certificate for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
  - **Legacy clients support:** *no enabled*
  - **Security policy:** TLSv1.2_2021 (recommended)
  - **Supported HTTP versions:** HTTP/2 (**no** HTTP/3)
  - **Default root object:** *empty*
  - **Standard logging:** On
  - **S3 bucket:** *an existing S3 bucket* (logging is working)
  - **Log prefix:** *empty*
  - **Cookie logging:** Off
  - **IPv6:** On
- Origin

  - **Origin domain:** [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
  - **Protocol:** HTTPS only
  - **HTTPS port:** 443
  - **Minimum origin SSL protocol**: TLSv1.2
  - **Origin path:** *empty*
  - **Add custom header:** *none*
  - **Enable Origin Shield:** No
  - **Additional settings:** *unchanged/default*
- Behaviors

  - **Path pattern:** Default (*)
  - **Origin and origin groups:** [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
  - **Compress objects automatically:** Yes
  - **Viewer protocol policy:** Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
  - **Allowed HTTP methods:** GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE
  - **Restrict viewer access:** No
  - Cache policy and origin request policy
  - **Cache policy:** CachingDisabled
  - **Origin request policy:** AllViewer
  - **Response headers policy:** *none*
  - **Smooth streaming:** No
  - **Field-level encryption:** *empty*
  - **Enable real-time logs:** No
  - **Function associations:** *none*

and the following Route 53 setup for example.com:

- **Apex Domain**: example.com
- example.com **A** *>>public IP of EC2 instance running the website<<*
- example.com **CAA** `0 issue "letsencrypt.org" 0 issue "amazonaws.com"`
- example.com **MX** *some MX configuration*
- example.com **NS** *AWS nameserver list*
- example.com **SOA** *default AWS entry*
- example.com **TXT** *SPF, domain validation, etc.*
- archive.example.com **A** *>>public IP of a separate EC2 instance running a different application<<*
- internal.example.com **A** *>>public IP of a separate EC2 instance running a different application<<*
- intranet.example.com **A** *>>public IP of a separate EC2 instance running a different application<<*
- public.example.com **A** *>>public IP of EC2 instance running the website<<*
- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) **A** **ALIAS to CloudFront distribution [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**

I thought this would be a pretty straight forward standard CloudFront configuration with caching disabled (for now). But no matter what I do, every request to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) results in a `403` error `Bad Request` from CloudFront immediately. CloudFront not even tries to connect the EC2 instance (at least there's nothing the logs). Error rate is 100% and the CloudFront logs do not provide any additional information. I'm not sure what to look for, what settings to change, basically what to do.

What can I do to debug the issue? Is there any obvious configuration mistake?

Comment: What are the security group rules attached to the origin EC2 server?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using the same domain as the CloudFront domain and the origin address. So CloudFront is going to see that as a request to itself, not to an EC2 server. You should use an Elastic IP address of the EC2 server as the origin address, or a load balancer address if you have a load balancer.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks a lot for your response. I looked odd to me as well, that the CloudFront domain is the same as the origin domain. Did not bother see too much however, because I thought AWS somehow solves this with this special "Alias" DNS record. So what you're saying is that I should e.g. allow the EC2 instance to serve content from, let's say, public.example.com (instead of redirecting to www.example.com) and set the CloudFron origin to public.example.com?

Comment: @MarkB Regarding security groups: basically the security group allows HTTP/HTTPS access from everywhere and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mark B! It is indeed a problem when the CloudFront domain - in this case [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - is the same as the origin address - again www.example .com. Thinking about it, it may be absolutely clear that this cannot work because there's an infinite loop between a request to the CloudFront distribution and the subsequent call to the origin. I just thought that the Route 53 **Alias** DNS record somehow deals with this magically.

The solution is to use a different domain for the origin. So in the example case the steps to solve the issue are:

- allow the EC2 instance (Nginx) to serve content from public.example.com, instead of redirecting to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- change the CloudFron origin address from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to public.example.com

This way requests to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) go to the CloudFront distribution which then requests data from public.example.com. And now everything works perfectly - and, I have to admit, as easy I'd have imagined it to work.